# How to parse this complex text-block into a multi-dimensional array, in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, multidimensional-array

I have a **complex** text-block; and, its content is:

```
    line_1(element_1,sub_line_1(sub_element_1,sub_element_2),element_2).
    line_2(sub_line_2(element_3,element_4),sub_line_3(sub_sub_line(element_5,element_6),element_7),element_8).
    ...
    line_n(element_a,element_b,element_c).
```

And, there is already an simple array, in PHP code:

```
$my_array = array();
```

Now, I want to parse into this PHP array, like:

```
$my_array = array (

    "line_1" => array (
            "element_1",
            "sub_line_1" => array (
                "sub_element_1",
                "sub_element_2" ),
            "element_2"),

    "line_2" => array (
            "sub_line_2" => array (
                "sub_element_3",
                "sub_element_4" ),
            "sub_line_3" => array (
                "sub_sub_line" => array ("element_5","element_6"),
                "sub_element_7" ),
            "element_8" )
    ),
    ...
    "line_n" => array ("element_a", "element_b", "element_c")

);
```

All data is **general**; and, the **level** of array is **more**. Could you help me to do it, with PHP?

Comment: Would you consider using `serialize()` and `unserialize()` instead? Then you have nothing to do... 8-)

Comment: The `serialize()` function transforms an array to a string, then the `unserialize()` function transforms it back. Otherwise you have to parse everything, maybe with `preg_split()`, with two loops since you want to break things down at two levels.

Comment: Why not format the text as json. Use php json functions.